# ng-init vs function in controller, which is better practice when using $parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a Bootstrap modal which corresponds to a ng-repeat list. I would like to access the ng-repeat scope data from its parent, which contains the modal. I do this so that when the modal button is clicked on the list, the corresponding data from the JSON appears in the modal.

I have found 2 ways of doing this, and I wonder which is the best alternative?

Method 1
View:

```
<li ng-init="myFunction(item,$parent)" ng-repeat="item in data.webapps_1.items>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.myFunction = function(item,parent){
        parent.selected=item.counter-1;
    };
```

Method 2 View:

```
<li ng-init="$parent.selected=item.counter-1" ng-repeat="item in data.webapps_1.items>
```

With nothing in the controller.

I have read in the Angular ngInit docs that

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

But the list of special properties of ngRepeat does not include $parent.

So, which is the better practice? Including the expression `$parent.selected=item.counter-1`in the controller or in ngInit directive?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the two fine really, so long as you're consistent. Depends on the scale of the app though.

IMO if the app is going to be large you'll want to go the function way, to better adhere to the whole MVC philosophy of decoupling and separation of concerns (http://victorblog.com/2013/03/18/angularjs-separation-of-concerns/).

```
ng-init="myFunction(item,$parent)"
```

It's a better structure because you want to keep most of your business logic in the javascript controllers, not in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the ng-init approach. Mainly for consistency of the timing of the call (i.e. more like an "onLoad" event). I understand the concerns regarding SoC and that makes sense as well. However, I have seen some specific scenarios (particularly pages with a lot of directives), when changing scope variables with the = binding in the (non ng-init) function, caused extra (premature) digest loops. Obviously it depends on what you're actually doing in the function as well as your scope bindings, but in my opinion its best to just avoid the situation and use the ng-init directive across the board. Your experience may obviously vary wildly. Like others said just pick an approach and stick with it and be aware of the impact of every call that you're making in the function itself. :)

EDIT: Regarding the accepted answer, the example was used passing values to the init function in ng-init. And hes correct that is a violation of the pattern. I typically use parameterless init functions and call it like:

```
ng-init="model.init()"
```

Any reference to $scope or what have you would happen inside the function itself. I rarely pass anything to init, unless its a static value. For example in several cases on an ASP.NET WebApi project, I wanted minimize round trips to the server so I would resolve a value from the MVC View Model, which is just rendered and passed as a string like so:

```
ng-init="model.init(@model.myValue)"
```

In those cases its usually best to keep it to simple value types (i.e. string, int, etc), but I have occasionally for small directives such as one that does nothing but display a dropdown, I have passed arrays to pre-populate the dropdown binding. Those cases are extremely situational and this one in particular would obviously only work when using server side rendering of the template.